# How compatible is CentOS in respect to hardware for desktop systems?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, drivers, hardware-compatibility

I have been tasked with creating a promotional/sales tool for our clients and sales people, (about 8400 users).  It's expected that the tool will be used on office and home systems.

The tool will run in Linux as a live DVD.  So after use, they can go back to windows.  For business reasons this must be done in Linux on a live dvd.  Windows is not an option.

MY question is which distro should be used as the OS if hardware compatibility is the OVERWHELMING concern. in addition to general hardware compatibility, the key compatibility issues are Video cards, sound cards, and network cards.

I was pushing for Ubuntu because I assume that Canonical has focused on hardware compatibility.

I know we are going to get phone calls, but we want to minimize tech support issues and more importantly, we must provide a good experience for our users.  Or the whole project could backfire.

Our contract programmer is pushing for CentOS. Is CentOS EXTREMELY hardware compatible?  As compatible as Ubuntu?

Would you recommend another distro that we have not thought of?

Answer (score 1):

I would say CentOS is probably not as hardware compatible as Ubuntu when it comes to recognizing a large array of hardware. Remember that CentOS derives from the Red Hat RHEL commercial product which predominately targets the server market. Ubuntu on the other hand primarily targets the Desktop market.

So I would expect better hardware support overall from Ubuntu for a larger swath of hardware than form CentOS.

Given all that you really need to come up with a minimum set of hardware that your DVD is targeted for and try and test the heck out of it. Also try and have a rough idea of the nature of what you'll be doing with the hardware prior since that will ultimately drive your selection.

For example:

- Need high end CPU?
- Video codecs?
- Sound/Audio support?
- Need Adobe Flash?
- Need specific video resolution(s)?

Given my experience I would expect the video to be the deal breaker in this endeavor. In general it's the most problematic thing in setting up a Linux system.

Comment: Thank sim, You are confirming everything I was thinking.  I did forget the other distro that is being pushed is the latest Debian.   As far as needs, at this time we are requiring 2 gigs of ram and a duel processor.  Video is another issue.  We are NOT flash and will not tax the video system at all.  We are considering Xfce 4.10 as it is lightweight and very functional. Our system should fine in 1 gig of ram.  We will test after completion  and may lower the minim recommended hardware.   I think the Debian option is also a very good way to go.

Comment: @JoeB - Yes Xfce is a good way to go. Lightweight and good performance.

Answer (score 1):

To echo and amplify [slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80651/1294) if you are looking for highest likelihood of *just working*, Ubuntu has probably hit more varied [desktop configurations than any other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution#Popular_distributions) considering that [DistroWatch's top 2](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=popularity) are Ubuntu and Mint (an Ubuntu derivative).

Yes, getting decent deployment statistics is like reading goat entrails, so the other is arguing from my (singular) personal experience. I've rescued a bunch of systems from "help! my Windows machine is so loaded with crapware that I don't know what to do" by carrying around Ubuntu on my keyring thumbdrive. It just works except for rare problems with old Broadcom WiFi hardware but I don't think any other mainstream distribution does any better.

I'd recommend 12.04 LTS as your base since Quetzal and Raring seem to be leaving some older hardware behind. There are a lot of services (lpr, dns, samba) which I'd take out if trying to make a turnkey demo. And of course, use the x86 architecture as there are ton of 32-bit machines still out there running XP.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with slm. CentOS is much more like RHEL with hardware compatibility. Fedora might be a good alternative, using many of the same or similar packages and using the same package manager YUM/RPM. Fedora is also targeted for the desktop so the hardware compatibility is much better.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Will look into it. our focuse right now is ubunto and Debian